# Using Case statement in Spark Dataframe in join condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can i use case condition while joining two dataframes in spark.

```
    var date_a = s"CASE WHEN month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'dd-MM-yyyy')))) 
    IN  (01,02,03) THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'dd-MM-yyyy'))))-1,'-')
    ,substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'dd-MM-yyyy')))),3,4)) 
    ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'dd-MM-yyyy')))),'-'),
    SUBSTR(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'dd-MM-yyyy'))))+1,3,4)) END"

    val gstr1_amend = df1.join(gstr1_amend_lkup_data, df1("date_b") === df2(date_a))
```

But am getting error case is not a column.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation with a minor diff, I wanted to use column from second data frame in case when column from first column is blank, and this is to be done only on joining. Couldn't use a case, however joined on another key column and used case in filter. Isn't elegant solution, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `case statement` in joining condition, add all conditions using `when & otherwise` functions inside `withColumn` and then use same column in join condition like below.

```
val df2 = somedf
.withColumn("date_a",when([...]).otherwise([...])) // [...] is your case statement logic

val gstr1_amend = df1.join(df2, df1("date_b") === df2("date_a"))
```